# Knockout observable array

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, knockout-3.0

In my ViewModel for my MVC4 application I have some code to get names from an ajax call and populate a simple control within my page, which is using Bootstrap 3.  As you can see below I have a hard-coded array which works perfectly.  With the ajax call, I see the data in the UI but it does not update my control and I have NO idea why.  I have verified the data exists and I have also tried setting self.Names = ko.observableArray within the ajax call.  Is there a simple reason why?  As I said I see the data within my form in both scenarios but I am not seeing the update I expect.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function ViewModel() {

        //Make the self as 'this' reference
        var self = this;
        //Declare observable which will be bind with UI
        self.Name = ko.observable("");

        var Names = {
            Name: self.Name
        };

        self.Name = ko.observable();
        //self.Names = ko.observableArray([{ Name: "Brian" }, { Name: "Jesse" }, { Name: "James" }]);
        self.Names = ko.observableArray();   // Contains the list of Names

        // Initialize the view-model
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetNames", "Home")',
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {
                self.Names(data); //Put the response in ObservableArray
            }
        });
    }

    var viewModel = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Here is the Response from the body via the ajax call:

```
[{"Id":1,"Name":"Brian"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Jesse"},{"Id":3,"Name":"James"}]
```

My HTML

```
<p>Current selection is <span data-bind="text:Name"></span></p>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-7 well">
        <form class="form-inline" action="#" method="get">
            <div class="input-group col-sm-8">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Work Section" name="q" type="text">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Select <span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-bind="foreach: Names">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" data-bind="text: Name, value: Name, click: function() {$root.Name(Name);}"></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <input name="category" class="category" type="hidden">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: how is the data array that the ajax call sees formatted?

Comment: It is returned from the controller as a JsonResult.

Comment: if the format doesn't match you will probably need to do a .each or .map to get data into a format your knockout can work with

Comment: I think Matt means what is that is the actual json. put that in your question so we can see it also.

Comment: I have made a tutorial on how to get this done (after many times trying on my own and forgetting how to do it again) [here in my blog](http://contractnamespace.blogspot.com/2014/02/ajax-dynamic-drop-downs-and-knockout.html)

Comment: @Dirnthelord, thanks for the example.  Looks promising BUT I am getting an error: Cannot call method 'fromJS' of undefined.  My call is a little different than your but I should be able to drop this into  my success portion of the ajax call...  success: function (data) {
                    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self.Names);
                }

Comment: @user2146538 You need knockout mapping library. I must have forgotten to mention that. I'm  sorry about there. You can [download it from here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the data coming in is either not structured the same as your bindings or observables are not set/updated properly. If they aren't observed then they wont update.

I'm not 100% sure on this, but I think you have to use the observable array functions in order for observers (UI elements bound to the array or its contents) to actually get updated. Basing this on a section from the [observable array documentation on the knockout site](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html):

> 2.For functions that modify the contents of the array, such as push and splice, KO’s methods automatically trigger the dependency tracking
>   mechanism so that all registered listeners are notified of the change,
>   and your UI is automatically updated.

Depending on the json, one way you might fix this is clear the observable array and reload it with data elements converted to observables:

```
self.Names.removeAll();
var newName = null;
for (var idx = 0; idx < data.length; idx++) {
    newName = data[idx];
    newName.Id = ko.observable(newName.Id);
    newName.Name = ko.observable(newName.Name);
    self.Names.push(newName);
}
```

On your html. the click function is using the Name property of the selected array element as the parameter. you don't want this, you want the latest value. So change this:

```
click: function() {$root.Name(Name);}
```

to this

```
//notice the new parenthesis after Name.
click: function() {$root.Name(Name());}
```

Comment: This didn't break anything but I am not seeing anything different.  Am I supposed to place all that code in the success: portion of the $.ajax call?

Comment: that or in a function the success function calls. can you show an example of the json returned by the ajax call in your question please

Comment: Hubson, I do have a property called Name in my array of Names.

Comment: I have added the Json returned at the bottom of my question.

Comment: Ok Hubson, I have two controls on the form.  One DIV that get updated and then an input box.  The DIV worked fine but now has this:  function observable() { if (arguments.length > 0) { // Write // Ignore writes if the value hasn't changed if (!observable['equalityComparer'] || !observable['equalityComparer'](_latestValue, arguments[0])) { observable.valueWillMutate(); _latestValue = arguments[0]; if (DEBUG) observable._latestValue = _latestValue; observable.valueHasMutated(); } return this; // Permits chained assignments } else { ...

Comment: I suggest you post your html also so we can see your data-bindings. it's hard to tell what's going on without that. I am suspicious that you have a Name property of your viewmodel, but it's not the same structure as what your ajax returns. yours is just a string, ajax is an object with Id and Name properties. The html should help figure this out

Comment: Added HTML above Hudson.

Comment: OK, I see the problem in your html. updated answer. moving this to chat for any further correspondance

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49262/discussion-between-hubson-bropa-and-user2146538)

Comment: Hubson, my work won't allow me into chat, ugh.  I am trying you changes now.

Comment: Hubson, so the <DIV> at the top is working again.  The input control still doesn't work.  I'm not sure what else to do at this point.  This should be easy as the JSON coming back from the call is exactly the same as the local array I hardcoded.  I don't understand this stuff at all.

Comment: I don't see an input being data bound in the html you put in the question. the Id and Name properties are observables now so the new array is not same structure as your hard-coded array. because of this you have to explicitly get the latest value, using (), when you want the value of a property.

Comment: Hubson, that is true, there is no data-bind="text:selectedName" within the input control.  I have tried adding that in every DIV without much success.  Seems I am really not getting this.

Comment: selectedName is not a property of your view model, but you do have Name, so use that instead of selectedName. It sounds like you are really close to understanding how this all goes together just missing a couple key connections. unfortunately this isn't the medium to go over those as it would be one helluva long conversation. Just keep at it, your close.